# Cannot override search box css rules in Doxygen

Tags: css, doxygen

I'm using *HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET* option to override default css rules. I can easily override some rules like **span.mlabel** or **.SelectItem** but **.SREntry** can't be overriden for some reason. In Firebug it's like my new rule never existed.

Css rules that I'm using:

```
   .SREntry {
        font-size: 10pt;
    }

    span.mlabel {
        font-size: 11pt;
    }

    .SelectItem {
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
```

**.SREntry** is responsible for formatting search box results. It's defined in *search.css* and it seems that no rule from this file can be overriden.

Why is that I can override rules defined in *doxygen.css* but not in *search.css*?

[EDIT] [Link](http://session13-001-site1.hostbuddy.com/) to generated documentation. It uses a custom css file *Custom.css* with described above rules.

Comment: Try using !important

Comment: did you try a.SelectItem ?

Comment: @Sleek I tried _!important_ but with no effect.

Comment: @albert You mean _a.SREntry_? Yes, I tried it also.

Comment: Provide a link please

Comment: @SleekGeek Here, [docs](http://session13-001-site1.hostbuddy.com). My custom css file is _Custom.css_.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, misread the question. I did mean SelectItem.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closer to html that generated by *search.js* at runtime you will find out that
`<iframe id="MSearchResults">` block contains another section of html document with
its own `<head>` section.

That is why you can't override this style.

```
<!--

 HTML header for doxygen 1.8.7

-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="cursor: auto ! important;">

    <head>
        ... removed some html here ...
        <script src="search/search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="search/search.css"></link>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top"></div>
        <div id="MSearchSelectWindow" onkeydown="return searchBox.OnSearchSelectKey(event)" onmouseout="return searchBox.OnSearchSelectHide()" onmouseover="return searchBox.OnSearchSelectShow()"></div>
        <!--

         iframe showing the search results (closed by defa…

        -->
        <div id="MSearchResultsWindow" style="display: block; top: 182px; left: 236px;">
            <iframe id="MSearchResults" frameborder="0" name="MSearchResults" src="javascript:void(0)">
                #document
                    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <title></title>
                            <meta content="text/xhtml;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"></meta>
                            <meta content="Doxygen 1.8.7" name="generator"></meta>
                            <link href="search.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
                            <script src="all_1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                            <script src="search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                        </head>
                        <body class="SRPage">

                        ... and so on...
```

You can fix this with either modifying *search.css* somehow or using
this kind of code in custom js file with *MutationObserver* or *setInterval* based solution. Notice the `../` in path, you need to go one level up to find correct css.

```
var cssLink = "../custom.css"

var searchDocument = document.getElementById("MSearchResults")
                     .contentWindow.document;

var head = searchDocument.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

var customStyle = searchDocument.createElement("link");
customStyle.setAttribute("href", cssLink);
customStyle.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
customStyle.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");

head.appendChild(customStyle);
```